# I don't understand what these does the Square Brackets means

Tags: javascript

I try to learn the string.search on "MND web doc", and I don't understand what does those **square brackets in the console.log()** part means.

Please give me some hint to help me. If anyone can show me some examples I'll say thank you very much.

```
var paragraph = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. If the dog barked, was it really lazy?';
var regex = /[^\w\s]/g;
console.log(paragraph[paragraph.search(regex)]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the doc for [the search function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search).

The brackets are here to index the paragraph at the index returned by the regex search. The regex is looking for any character that is not a space or a word character. It finds the dot at index 43 so `paragraph.search(regex)` returns 43, which is used to index into the paragraph string (an array of characters), and that returns `.`.

```js
const paragraph = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. If the dog barked, was it really lazy?';

const regex = /[^\w\s]/g;

console.log('index:', paragraph.search(regex));

console.log('char at index:', paragraph[paragraph.search(regex)]);
```